# I want to change my gender (transgender) mtf

Tags: halal-haram

I am biologically a male and am thankful for this blessing from Allah, alothough I struggle with attraction to males and I have been very feminine since young. A fatwa came out in pakistan giving transgender people the right to marry, and Dr. Shabir Ally whom I listen to said he sees no problem with it. Other shia or sufi and even some sunni scholars have permitted it, but still I am not sure. I asked Allah for a sgin and I actually got one, though still I am uncertain. kuntha (intersex) were not able to marry with ambiguous genitals before surgery was available, does that not mean if a transgender gets surgery they can identify as their chosen gender and get marries, please try to at least understand my position here, if I could I would be very religious and wear a hijab and observe haya, this would prevent me from committing haram as I struggle with many temptations that are for females, Allah tells us the male is not the same as the female, but I feel exactly like a female, does Allah decide our gender or our biological gender, and would this count as a necessity since it would cause me great harm if I don't transition. I really need this, what should I do, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

These are some Hadith as the basis to prohibit transgender:

> Narrated Ibn `Abbas: Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) cursed those men who are in the similitude (assume the manners) of women and those women who are in the similitude (assume the manners) of men.

`(Sahih Bukhari)`

> Narrated Ibn 'Abbas:
>   "The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) cursed the women who imitate men and the men who imitate women."

`(Jami' at-Tirmidhi)`

> Narrated Ibn 'Abbas: The Prophet (ﷺ) cursed women who imitate men and men who imitate women.

`(Sunan Abu Dawud)`

> It was narrated from Abu Hurairah: that the Messenger of Allah cursed women who imitate men and men who imitate women.

`(Sunan Ibn Majah)`

Comment: Is there any sin on me if I believe it is halal and other Islamic scholars like Dr. Shabir Ally agree?

Comment: I disagree with Dr. Shabir Ally because he didnt give enough basis for his claim

Comment: Its better to be patient brother, life is short, you'll be asked about pleasure (At-Takathur 102:8)

Comment: I have been patient wallahi, but knowing that there is debate on the issue while for homosexuality it's certain that it's haram, makes me question why I am going through such unnesecary difficulty, I have always wanted to be a girl, I am only attracted to males, does it make sense that I continue living as a male when there is an easier route that may not be haram? Scholars have allowed hermaphrodites to choose their gender if biology isn't clear, our psycholgy dictates our life so much more than out physical appearance, I rlly need to transition. And I pray to Allah, I beg Him to accept this.